# pdflib - is there's a way to rotate the page of pdf

Tags: pdflib

***before rotate***
this is what i generate, with A4 Page.
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fb5p.png)

***after rotate***
after generate, i wanna rotate the page like this.

please help me.
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJYGe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible!

Have a look at the [PDFLib Cookbook](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/) (great resource for learning!), more specifically the sample for [`rotate_pages`](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdf_import/rotate_pages/).

Basically you import a page into a document and place it with a new orientation. That will "rotate" the page as you like.

PHP sample code from the cookbook:

```php
/* Loop over all pages of the input document */
for ($pageno = 1; $pageno <= $endpage; $pageno++)
{
    $page = $p->open_pdi_page($indoc, $pageno, "");

    if ($page == 0)
        throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());

    /* Page size may be adjusted by fit_pdi_page() */
    $p->begin_page_ext(0, 0, "width=a4.width height=a4.height");

    /* Place the imported page on the output page. Adjust the page size
    * automatically to the size of the imported page. Orientate the
    * page to the west; similarly you can orientate it to the east or
    * south, if required.
    */
    $p->fit_pdi_page($page, 0, 0, "adjustpage orientate=west");

    $p->close_pdi_page($page);

    $p->end_page_ext("");
}
```